# PHP Paypal City error

Tags: php, paypal, city

im using the simple paypal checkout (Buy Now) Which works great with items from the Database,

The only problem is; im using Adress_Override, but i get an error whenever i get to the payment page;

[image]

> **There is a problem with the sendingadres. We marked this RED (the white arrow) Change the adress and continue paying with paypal.**

And under that it says:

**This webshop told us to use the sendingadres input from the webshop, and theres a problem with this adres, go back to the webshop to change it.**

this is what i use:

```
        <input type='hidden' name='address_override' value='1'>
        <input type='hidden' name='address1' value='Nee'>
        <input type='hidden' name='first_name' value='".$_SESSION['username']."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='last_name' value='".$_SESSION['username']."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='country' value='NL'>
        <input type='hidden' name='city' value='Arnhem'>
```

Why am i getting this error?

Thanks in advance ! :D

Comment: where is the comma coming from? And no zipcode?

Comment: So i added the ZIP part, and now i dont get the error anymore thanks!